# Python create text file without newline intepretation

Tags: python, subprocess, newline

I'm starting with python and i'm creating a script who will run valgrind and all the binairies in the folder, catch the output and create text file if the result need to be checked. My problem is that i get the output but when i print it or write it into a new file, \n charactere are not interpreted and display like two charactere, not as a newline that they should.

## how I catch the output

```
proc.append(subprocess.Popen(
        ['valgrind','--track-origins=yes','--leak-check=full',''.join(['./',files[i]])],
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
        universal_newlines=True,
        shell=False,
        ))
    print '--> valgrind on', files[i]
    stdout_value.append(proc[j].communicate())
```

## how I write it in a new file

```
        file = open(''.join([os.getcwd(),'/valgrind_output_dir/',result4.group(1),'_output.txt']), "w")
    file.write(str(stdout_value[i]))
```

Thanks to tell me what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Remove `str()` from `file.write`, so its `file.write(stdout_value[i])`

Comment: Which operating system? Have you tried to open the result file in binary mode?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid i have this error message if i do this: file.write(stdout_value[i])
TypeError: expected a character buffer object

Comment: What text editor you are using to open file ? have you tried with other ones?

Comment: @guidot, i open the file that i create in binary mode but its change nothing..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one:

```
import subprocess
with open("file", "wb") as new_file:
    proc = []
    proc.append(subprocess.Popen(
            ["ls", "-l"],
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,
            universal_newlines=True,
            shell=False,
            ))
    new_file.write(proc[0].communicate()[0])
```

Problem may be: proc[0].communicate() => (TEXT, NONE)

> **Popen.communicate(input=None)**
>
> Interact with process: Send data to
> stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached.
> Wait for process to terminate. The optional input argument should be a
> string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be
> sent to the child.
>
> communicate() returns a **tuple (stdoutdata, stderrdata)**.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand what exactly you want me to do

Comment: I am just saying:
 
Instead of:
file.write(str(stdout_value[i]))

USE:
file.write(stdout_value[i][0])

Comment: Thank you its working!!! Ok I understand i just write the stdout from the tuple and not the entire tuple as I did before..

Comment: You are welcome. You can check mark, if your problem is solved. Welcome to StackOverflow.